# overflow scroll box with position fixed buttons inside

Tags: html, css, web

I have an overflow:scroll; box with long width content and 2 buttons
[like so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ls9v.png)

The problem is that the buttons are not positioned at the end of the scroll box [look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPznm.png)

I even have made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bananoga/70vy13ke/12/

that`s my css:

```
.scroll-div{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width:100%;
  height: 110px;
  overflow: scroll;
  contain: content;
  display: flex;
}

.inside-box{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.buttons{
   position: fixed; 
    left: auto;
    right: 19px;
    bottom: 5px;
    margin-top:5px;
}
```

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

By setting `position: fixed` on `.buttons` you removed it from the normal flow of the document and instead had it positioned relative to the closest parent context. Since you had `contain: content` on `.scroll-div`, that was your nearest context, and `.buttons` was set a fixed distance from it's bounds. Note that this is not the same as the bounds of the content of `.scroll-div`, but its outer container.

By removing `position: fixed` and the associated styles, the buttons show up to the right of the last instance of `.filter`:

```css
.scroll-div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  overflow: scroll;
  display: flex;
}

.filter {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-div">
  <div class="filter"></div>
  <div class="filter"></div>
  <div class="filter"></div>
  <div class="filter"></div>
  <div class="filter"></div>
  <div class="filter"></div>
  <div class="filter"></div>
  <div class="filter"></div>
  <div class="filter"></div>
  <div class="filter"></div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="btn1">
    button1
    </button>
    <button class="btn2">
    button2
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Edit

Based on the clarification in your comment:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  align-items: start;
}

.filter {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.filter:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="filter">Filter Content</div>
  <div class="filter">Filter Content</div>
  <div class="filter">Filter Content</div>
  <div class="filter">Filter Content</div>
  <div class="filter">Filter Content</div>
  
  <!--
    This div will wrap both the last filter and
    the buttons below it to allow for the desired
    layout to be achieved without brittle hacks.
  -->
  <div>
    <div class="filter">
      Filter Content
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>Button 1</button>
      <button>Button 2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course, it is. this is not what I want. I want the buttons to be positioned on the bottom of the scroll-div right under the last filter. and be one next to each other like the second image I attached.